# Get posts with unique titles in WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query that takes posts of different types with the same title. Instead, I want to pull only posts with unique titles.

My query so far is as follows:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => ['report', 'case-study', 'event'],
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_get,
    'post__not_in' => [$post->ID]
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

However, this does not filter only unique titles.

I can get a list of unique titles using 
`$uniques = array_unique($titles);` but that does not get me the actual posts. I wanted to know if there was a query method along the lines of  `'post__title_not_in => $uniques;`

I tried searching everywhere for this, but I was not able to find anything that worked. Would greatly appreciate any help.